# How can I set the request header for curl?

Tags: curl

How would I pass multiple values in the header for a `curl` request?

Comment: Do you have an example you're using right now that you could show us?

Comment: add multiple -H flag. For example `curl -H "Content-Type : application/json" -H "Authorization : Token token='yourtokenhere'"`

Comment: How do you feel about accepting an answer below? I like mine heh ;)  @Noel Yap

Answer (score 385):

Just use the `-H` option several times:

```
curl -H "Accept-Charset: utf-8" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://www.some-domain.example
```

Comment: What if the header contains `"`?

Comment: @Freewind wrap the value with a single-quote instead of a double, or escape it. Same thing you always do in that case.

Answer (score 85):

To pass multiple headers in a curl request you simply add additional `-H` or `--header` to your curl command.

**Example**

```
//Simplified
$ curl -v -H 'header1:val' -H 'header2:val' URL

//Explanatory
$ curl -v -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  https://www.example.com
```

**Going Further**

For standard HTTP header fields such as *User-Agent*, *Cookie*, *Host*, there is actually another way to setting them. The curl command offers designated options for setting these header fields:

- -A (or --user-agent): set "User-Agent" field.
- -b (or --cookie): set "Cookie" field.
- -e (or --referer): set "Referer" field.
- -H (or --header): set "Header" field

For example, the following two commands are equivalent. Both of them change "User-Agent" string in the HTTP header.

```
    $ curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: UserAgentString" https://www.example.com
    $ curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -A "UserAgentString" https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 63):

Sometimes changing the header is not enough, some sites check the referer as well:

```
curl -v \
     -H 'Host: restapi.some-site.com' \
     -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
     -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6' \
     -e localhost \
     -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36' \
     'http://restapi.some-site.com/getsomething?argument=value&argument2=value'
```

In this example the referer (-e or --referer in curl) is 'localhost'.

Answer (score 3):

Set Header **-H "Content-Type: application/json"** using GET Request

Example -

> `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`

**If u want to Add multiple header**

> `curl -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Content-Type: application/json  -X GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`

[image]