# How to download a binary file from private Github repository?

Tags: git, http, curl, github, wget

I am trying to download the latest release from one of my private repositories and I am using this code to download it:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token $AUTH_KEY" \
https://api.github.com/repos/haccks/Test/releases/latest
```

the response from the above request returns asset id (`7052110`) along with other details. Then I used

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
https://$AUTH_KEY:@api.github.com/repos/haccks/Test/releases/assets/7052110
```

and getting this error:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

I tried `wget` also

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --header='Accept: application/octet-stream' \ 
https://$AUTH_KEY:@api.github.com/repos/haccks/Test/releases/assets/7052110
```

which returns:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-15 20:46:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

What's went wrong?

Comment: I think that your curl code is no problem. I thought that your asset ID may be wrong. Because when I tried to retrieve the binary file from releases page using wrong asset ID, I confirmed the same error. For example, the asset ID can be retrieved by ``curl -H "Authorization: token $AUTH_KEY" https://api.github.com/repos/haccks/Test/releases/latest | jq '.assets[0].id'``. Please be careful this array index of ``.assets[0].id``. The binary file you want may be ``.assets[1].id``. So you can retrieve binary data using the asset ID. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike; This gives me `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9`

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I cannot see your code and responses. So I cannot estimate under the situation. I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike; Do I have to give you access to my private repository?

Comment: No No. I worry about that it may occur problems for security. So I cannot access your private repository. I think that if I can know the structure of JSON response, it will lead to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since `-H "Authorization: token $AUTH_KEY"` worked for the previous API calls, you can try with [a `curl` with multiple headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212535/6309):

```
curl -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
-H "Authorization: token $AUTH_KEY" \
https://api.github.com/repos/haccks/Test/releases/assets/7052110
```

Answer (score 0):

add the
curl -L -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" -H "Authorization: token xxxxxxxx" [https://api.github.com/repos/[user]/[repo]/releases/assets/74640834](https://api.github.com/repos/%5Buser%5D/%5Brepo%5D/releases/assets/74640834) --output "filename"