# How do I authenticate with Curl and JWT in the Bolt CMS Rest API?

Tags: curl, jwt, bolt-cms

I'm trying to use a Rest API for Bolt CMS, but I'm unable to perform a basic login using the examples provided in the readme. Eventually I'll implement it in C# but I'm just trying to test the basic functionality with Curl at the moment.

Here's the readme file:
https://github.com/serweb-labs/bolt-rest-api/blob/master/README.md

When I run the line

```
curl -X POST -H "https://example.com/auth/login?username=myuser&password=mypass"
```

I get the response: **curl: no URL specified!**

I assume I'm missing somemthing really basic, as I've never worked with curl or this type of authentication before.

Comment: The argument after `-H` is supposed to be a header, so your command is missing the URL. Try removing `-H` from your command. For an example of  curl's header option see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212503/how-can-i-set-the-request-header-for-curl

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had tried that too with no success (the site responds but not with what I expect). When I visit the URL there is an error too:

MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouterListener.php line 183: 
No route found for "GET /auth/login": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST, OPTIONS)

I think it's a bug or configuration issue with the extension so I've posted an issue on GitHub.

Comment: No answer after posting the issue on GitHub or contacting author by mail, I assume this plugin is no longer supported so I've decided not to use it.